# Angular4: Post deployment issue

Tags: angular, deployment, angular2-routing

I have built an Angular4 application and everything works well but after deployment I have faced a strange issue.
I have 3 routes:
`/` : for the `AppComponent`
`/login` : for the `LoginComponent`
`/editor`: for my `EditorComponent`
In development mode when I write in the url bar of the navigator `localhost://4200/login` or `localhost://4200/editor` works fine but when I do it after deployment I get `404 Page not found` !!
But when I use the `routerLink` of Angular like `<a routerLink="/login">Login</a>` and click on it, I get redirected to the `LoginComponent` successfully !!
Why (after deployment) when I use the routerLink everything works fine but if I try to access the component directly from the navigator's url bar I get `404 Page not found` ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a 404 error when refreshing or directly accessing your application since the actual address within the browser is updating ( without # approach).

> If you want not having a 404 error, you need to update your server to
>   serve the index.html file for each route path you defined.

If you want to switch to the HashBang approach, you need to use this configuration:

**In AppModule.ts**

```
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';  

providers:[
 {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
]
```

In this case, when you refresh the page, it will be displayed again (but you will have a # in your address).

Comment: in which file should I declare the HashBang approach ?

Comment: in appmodule.ts file in providers array

Comment: but in that case I must add `#` to any url if I want to access directly from the navigator's bar ?!

Comment: @SlimenTunis yes thats a down side to it. Or configure your server. Where have you deployed it

Comment: Sorry for those questions but can you provide me a link or documentation to read more about how to configure my server ?

Comment: I'm using wamp server